# Add dynamic text to a p tag

Tags: jquery

I have a p tag that has some styled text inside it I want to keep that style and when I click a button with Jquery I want to add new text to it.
It was all working well until I tried to add a br tag to my text then it displays the br tag as part of the text.

```
button.click(function(evt){
  var td = $(this).closest('td'); 
  date.find('.chosen').text( td.data('day') + ' May ' + td.data('date') + "'</br>'" + $(this).text() );
}
```

If I use html() it will remove my styling from my p tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - A line break looks like this: `<br />`

2 - You are double quoting, it should just be `+ "<br />" +`

3 - You should use `.html` instead of `.text` for insertion:

```
button.click(function(evt){
  var td = $(this).closest('td'); 
  date.find('.chosen').html( td.data('day') + ' May ' + td.data('date') + "<br />" + $(this).text() );
}
```